# Load device function from shared library with dlopen

Tags: cuda

I'm relatively new to cuda programming and can't find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to have a shared library, lets call it `func.so`, that defines a device function

`__device__ void hello(){ prinf("hello");}`

I then want to be able to access that library via dlopen, and use that function in my programm. I tried something along the following lines:

`func.cu`

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void(*pFCN)();

__device__ void dhello(){
    printf("hello\n")
}

__device__ pFCN ptest = dhello;
pFCN h_pFCN;

extern "C" pFCN getpointer(){
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_pFCN, ptest, sizeof(pFCN));
    return h_pFCN;
}
```

`main.cu`

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*fcn)();
typedef fcn (*retpt)();
retpt hfcnpt;
fcn hfcn;

__device__ fcn dfcn;
__global__ void foo(){
    (*dfcn)();
}
int main() {
    void * m_handle = dlopen("gputest.so", RTLD_NOW);
    hfcnpt = (retpt) dlsym( m_handle, "getpointer");
    hfcn = (*hfcnpt)();
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dfcn, &hfcn, sizeof(fcn), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    foo<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

But this way I get the following error when debugging with cuda-gdb:

```
CUDA Exception: Warp Illegal Instruction

Program received signal CUDA_EXCEPTION_4, Warp Illegal Instruction.
0x0000000000806b30 in dtest () at func.cu:5
```

I appreciate any help you all can give me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a `__device__` function in one compilation unit from device code in another compilation unit requires [separate compilation with device linking](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda) usage of `nvcc`.

However, such usage with *libraries* [only works with static libraries](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#libraries).

Therefore if the target `__device__` function is *in* the `.so` library, and the calling code is *outside* of the `.so` library, your approach cannot work, with the current `nvcc` toolchain.

The only "workarounds" I can suggest would be to put the desired target function in a static library, or else put both caller and target inside the same `.so` library.  There are a number of questions/answers on the cuda tag which give examples of these alternate approaches.